# create word document dynamically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I need to create a word document at run time by using vb.net . how can I do that? I created the excel file before, but don't know how use it for word . here is what I use for create the Excel file:

```
 Sub export_to_excel(recordCount As Integer, DataArray(,) As Object, fileName_Location As String)

    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim oBook As Object
    Dim oSheet As Object

    ''Start a new workbook in Excel.
    oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add

    ''Add headers to the worksheet on row 1.
    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    '  For i = 0 To headers.Count - 1
    oSheet.Range("A1").Value = "AAA"
    oSheet.Range("B1").Value = "BBB"
    oSheet.Range("C1").Value = "CCC"
    oSheet.Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
    'Next


    ''Transfer the array to the worksheet starting at cell A2.
    oSheet.Range("A2").Resize(recordCount, 3).Value = DataArray

    ''Save the Workbook and quit Excel.
    oBook.SaveAs(fileName_Location)
    oSheet = Nothing
    oBook = Nothing
    oExcel.Quit()
    oExcel = Nothing
    GC.Collect()


End Sub
```

How can I use something like this code to create word file?

Comment: without using the interop, you don't have many choices. perhaps take a look at Aspose library: http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx

Comment: you are using interop in the example, but you say you don't want to use interop? Which one is it?

Comment: @Ahmed ilyas: Aspose is very expensive compared to the OpenXML SDK

Comment: it was just a suggestion.... there are many sure, but this was one suggestion from experience. Alternatively the original COM approach would be free and work but the OP didn't want to go down this route thus an alternative was given especially used in the enterprise industry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this.

But first of all you are using interop in your example and you can do the same with word. There is a good example of this on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316383)

If you do not need any fonts or anything you can always write to a textfile and use the extention .doc which will open it in word without any problem.

The 3rd and best solution is using Open XML which is the new way of manipulating office documents (extension docX). This format is just plain xml and you can manipulate it as pure text or xml or you can use the open xml sdk which gives you exellent way to manipulate word through a modern interface. This works with office 2007 and up. Documentation is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx)